# Any good Gtk libraries out there?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

Any good Gtk libraries out there? I know of Holly Gtk Widgets, any other good ones out there?

***Are there any good ones for menubar or toolbar ? Thanks!***

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Medsphere Widgets](http://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets), with a good graph widget, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop has a docking library and text/source editor widget that have no dependencies on the rest of MD.

In addition, MonoDevelop and Banshee both have some good widgets that would be relatively easy to extract.

Comment: Are there any good ones for menubar or toolbar ? Thanks!

Comment: MonoDevelop has dockable toolbars that could be pulled out without much difficulty. What do you want from a toolbar or menubar that isn't in the default GTK ones?

Comment: One that would look good in windows aswell...

Comment: Just look at what you can make with MFC Feature Pack 2008 and later. It blows all what GTK/KDE has at the moment out of the water.

Answer (score 0):

How about [GTK+ OpenGL extension](http://gtkglext.sourceforge.net/) for plugging OpenGL graphics into your application?

Answer (score 0):

The VMWare team have a few simple but nice widgets in their open source pool.

Edit: Sorry saw you tagged it with C#. This widgets are written in C